# Where to put ServiceLoader config file in a web app

Tags: java, eclipse, serviceloader

I am writing a web app in Eclipse.

I am trying to use the ServiceLoader class to load some plugins.

The docs for ServiceLoader say I need to place a file in META-INF/services.

I have placed the file in the WebContent/META-INF/service folder but when I run the JUnit test via Eclipse it does not find any plugins.

Is this the correct location for the file?

Also, how can I get more debug info from ServiceLoader such as the folders it is searching for the file in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The META-INF/services should be at the root of the jar file or resource directory in the classpath of the classloader used to locate plugins.

If you have a web application, then you can have directory structure like:

```
<webappname>/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services
```

But the ideal way is to have it in your plugin's jar file. E.g if you have a plugin bundled as `WEB-INF/lib/myplugin.jar`, and your plugin class is `com.example.plugin.MyPlugin`  Then the jar should have a structure:

```
myplugin.jar!/META-INF/services/com.example.plugin.MyPlugin
```

Having done that, you can get a service loader using your web application's class loader

Comment: OK, I have got it working now!

Never would have guessed it goes in the WEB-INF folder!

I will use you idea of creating a JAR file for it later when I get a Ant script going.

Comment: @Leith cool, but make that change (about jar files) sooner than later :)